# Screen on/off detection

Tags: android

here i am trying to determine whether the screen is on or not but it doesn't seems to be working when press power lock/unlock button. Application works with no error but the code in if-else doesnt seems to have effect. 
**Edited**
now the code work(thanks **Olgun**) but the mediaplayer playback doesnt stops and every time on/off screen new mediaplayer objct is created(multiple playbacks ).

**SCBroadcaster.java**

```
    public class SCBroadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver {
    PowerManager pm;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(arg0, R.raw.gale);
        if (arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                    mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "oNONONO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            mp.start();
        }

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    BroadcastReceiver bre = new SCBroadcaster();
    registerReceiver(bre, filter);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (SCBroadcaster.wasScreenOn) {
        System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");
    } else {

    }
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!SCBroadcaster.wasScreenOn) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON check out for above broadcasts registration. [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) you can find a good example.

Comment: the code in the link works fine but even after using the stop and release methods the mediaplayer playbacks doesnt stops

Comment: @PrimožKralj why not?

Answer (score 15):

The approach with the ACTION_SCREEN did not work for me. After some different solutions this code finally solved the problem for me:

```
/**
 * Is the screen of the device on.
 * @param context the context
 * @return true when (at least one) screen is on
 */
public boolean isScreenOn(Context context) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        boolean screenOn = false;
        for (Display display : dm.getDisplays()) {
            if (display.getState() != Display.STATE_OFF) {
                screenOn = true;
            }
        }
        return screenOn;
    } else {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        //noinspection deprecation
        return pm.isScreenOn();
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach also solved for me, because I only needed to treat the case when the screen was on or off for onPause(). For a case where you needed to treat if the screen was on or off before onResume() you should use a different approach.

Comment: What is happen if screen on with lock. I think the above solution cannot detect it

Comment: This works, but it's quite slow. 100's of miliseconds according to the profiler. Better not do it on the main therad.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding this inside your activity.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(); 
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF); 
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver(); 
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Similarly you can add for `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` also

Answer (score 0):

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` in a backgroung `Service` for  `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` events. It worked for me.