# Android how to receive Broadcast when Screen is ON

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I was able to receive Screen state when the app is running, but when the app is stop I can't receive it.

here my code *LockService*

```
public class LockService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    Log.e("Action","Screen");
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    Log.e("Sample","Screen");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LockService getService() {
        return LockService.this;
    }
}
}
```

*BroadcastReceiver*

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Intent intent;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Log.e("Screen state"," ON");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

*MainActivity* in the onCreate activity

```
 startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockService.class));
```

*Manifest.xml*

```
<service android:name=".LockService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_USER_PRESENT"/>

    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I want to start an Activity when user wake the phone

Comment: Hi, take a look at this question and answers. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13307565/5241603

Comment: is it work even the app is stop?

Comment: the link works only if the app is running

Comment: try to stops service on onstop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code works. Just my phone unstable, I reformat my phone then my app works perfectly. Thanks for devote.

phone:Xiaomi Mi 5
OS:Android 6.0